# Calculate third and fourth nearest neighbours in fcc packing

Tags: physical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography

My textbook has given data for third and fourth nearest neighbours to be 6 and 8 with distances  a and √(3/2)a.

I have been able to calculate for the first and second nearest neighbour but it has become difficult to visualise for the other two to calculate. Can you help me with hints on how to proceed preferably with a diagram.

Comment: Does crystal has FCC structure or NaCl like structure?

Comment: Crystal has fcc structure surrounded by n number of identical atoms around it.

Comment: I don't understand "n atoms surrounded by it". Is there any description of n given in exact question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a mistake in your textbook, when it states that there is a neighbor at a distance $a√(3/2)$. It should have been written $a(√3)/2$. I explain and develop this point now.

Let's start from any apex of the elementary cubic cell. The nearest neighbors of any apex in FCC are the atoms in the middle of a face. And there are $8$ such atoms, at a distance $(a√2)/2 = 0.707 a$. The next neighbors are in the center of the cube, and there are $8$ such atoms, at a distance $(a√3)/2 = 0.866 a$. The third next neighbors are the $6$ next apexes, with a distance $a$. And the fourth next neighbors are the $8$ atoms at the opposite apexes on each face, with a distance $a√2 = 1.414 a$.

Comment: How second neighboura are in centre of cube as in FCC atoms are present on middle of faces and vertices of cube not in centre of cune?